# Is it correct to say "You can not put this dress on from top down. Put it on from bottom up"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

There are some special dresses that we can not put the dress on by putting it over our heads, but rather put our legs in the dress first and then pull it all the way up to the chest.

Is it correct to say "**You can not put this dress on from top down. Put it on from bottom up**"?

I couldn't see the phrases "**from top down**" or "**from bottom up**" in dictionaries mentioning this.

Comment: It should definitely be "from **the** top down" or "from **the** bottom up", since these are a specific top and bottom that we are talking about.  You can find examples of these phrases with a web search.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't know what you meant if you said that. Here's a short passage from a [wedding site](https://vowdweddings.com/the-guide-planning/try-at-home-party.html) that has the phrases I'd use:

> If the dress has a back zipper, you will **step into the dress**. If the dress has a side zipper, you will **pull it over your head**

Hopefully it's clear which one's which without further explanation.